# Skip Dialog Boxes using Photoshop script?

Tags: scripting, photoshop

I am trying to disable the pop up warning message for one particular action . Basically that action is subtracting the transparency channel of all the layer from one base layer .I have to click enter to move on to the next step even after I automate the batch action . I have no knowledge on coding . Any ideas where I can study/ get help to avoid these pop ups using scripting. Thank you in advance

I tried googling where I can get atleast the code alone to attack to the action .I know without knowing scripting knowledge this would be a mess but I need to atleast get this as I have to do this on daily basis for atleast 100 images .

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the Actions Palette there's a tick and icon that looks like a rectangle with a line at the top. Click that off and it'll affect the whole action and switch off any annoying dialogue boxes.

Or have

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF
```

at the start of your script.

[image: action toggle dialogue off]

Comment: Yeah I tried  toggle on/off option but it's not helping still I get atleast 20 popup for every image. Also I installed script listener plug in  can I get my actions into script there ? . Or where can I get my action as script exactly.